# Set Samsung S3370b as USB Modem?

Tags: 12.04, samsung, mobile-broadband

Back when I had a Windows PC; I used an application called "Samsung Kies" with my S3370b Mobile Phone (not Smartphone). A feature that was included in the software, was the ability to use the phone as a Modem for Mobile Internet.

So my Question is, whether or not I can use Samsung Kies on Ubuntu to use that feature, or if there is a better alternative way.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no "Samsung Kies" version for Ubuntu, but the following should work:

Connect your phone to your box via usb.In Ubuntu go to the network applet and click on it, next click on edit connections, next click on the tab Mobile Broadband, next click on add.
Your phone should be listed beneath "Create a connection for this mobile broadband device".
Click continue, now you have to answer a number of questions regarding your provider and billing plan. You might also have to provide the access point name. You probably won't have to change anything in the editing new connection window, just save and try out your new connection.